# Positioning background relatively to right bottom using px values

Tags: css

I wan to position the `background-image` in a certain distance from right and bottom.
I don't want to use `right borrom` since it will position it in the corner, and % or distance from `left top` prevent my design from being responsive.
is there a CSS solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could try something like this with **calc.**

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url(http://www.bcebhagalpur.ac.in/images/Facebook.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc(100% - 40px) calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor set amet etc etc etc etc .....</p>
</div>
```

Or you could do it with just 4 sides positioning:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url(http://www.bcebhagalpur.ac.in/images/Facebook.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 40px bottom 40px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor set amet etc etc etc etc .....</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.position
{
position:fixed;
right:200px;
bottom:150px;
}
```